# How do I Undelete a Bootcamp drive back to NTFS

Tags: macos, bootcamp, ntfs, fsck

I have a recently formatted an (MS-DOS)Fat disk inside my mac.

The problem is, this was my BOOTCAMP drive formatted in NTFS.

I have read a bit on how to use fsck to (undelete) a drive and watched a few youtube vids. And am fairly comfortable with the terminal.

For example "sudo fsck_ntfs -d /dev/disk1s1" or "sudo fsck_exfat -d /dev/disk1s1

However, none mention this PEBCAK problem.

How do I get the original drive back? What is the magic sequence to get from FAT to NTFS with most of the files back?

Thanks in advance

Ryan

Comment: This would be better asked in a windows help forum, since what you're doing doesn't really have anything to do with macos. That said, you need a data recovery app that can find deleted file. The problem is, doing this gives you a mess. You'll get many versions of the same file from different times it was saved, you'll likely lose file names and other metadata. If theres a few important documents you are after, it may work. But if you need a drive full of files back, it's going to be a real long messy process.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite suspicious about if such commands as "fsck_xxx" will meet your purpose. These commands usually aim to check the corrupted file system or broken file links. Under your situation, if the partition had been kept the size unchanged while formatting it into FAT32 from NTFS, maybe this software named "Disk Drill 3" could carry out “quick scan or deep scan" to locate the ntfs files before the format. So I suggest following steps:

1, Check out the free version "disk drill 3" software for MacOS, https://www.cleverfiles.com/file-system-recovery-mac.html. Contact with the technical guys of the company may get better understanding of your concern and suggestions.

2, Running "preview of all recovery method" function of the free version software to check if there are any recognizable files on the bootcamp partition.

3, If nothing could be found on that FAT32-format partition, use the MacOS's disk utilities to reformat the partition back to NTFS; repeat step 2 again.

4, If you found the files and think them worthy of the money for the Pro version, pay and use the pro version to do the deep scan and get recovery of your files.

I never use this "disk drill" software to recover files in a formatted bootcamp partition. Hope you good luck and find all your files back.